Exporting Subtotals and Totals as seen on dashboard into excel
When I currently export from a a pivot table in Looker Data Studio Dashboard, it only exports the data and not the subtotals and totals.
I’m looking to export the data with subtotals and totals as seen on Looker Data Studio dashboard
I tried exporting and it only exported the data without the subtotals and totals
